# Show products related to same transaction together (Telerik Kendo UI Grid Jquery)

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am trying to show all the products together which belongs to the same transaction with their Quantity.

Here is my code but it shows two different items in a different row in a grid that belongs to the same transaction/Order ID.

**View Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            PurchaseAmount: {
              type: "number"
            },
            Rewards: {
              type: "number"
            },
            Date: {
              type: "date"
            }


          }
        }
      },
      transport: {
        read: {

          url: "@Url.Action("
          GetRewardList ", "
          MyAccount ")",
          dataType: "json"
        }
      },
      //pageSize: 10
    },
    detailTemplate: "<div class='bd-callout bd-callout-warning'><div class='alert alert-success p-2 my-2'><i class='fa fa-database pl-2 pr-2' aria-hidden='true'></i> Redemption Order: #: transID #</div><div>Item: #: Product # </div><div>Item Description: #: OfferDesc #</div><div>Quantity: #:Quantity #</div></div>",
    //height: 800,
    //groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: {
      extra: false,
      operators: {
        string: {
          startswith: "Starts with",
          eq: "Is equal to",
          neq: "Is not equal to"
        }
      }
    },

    columns: [{
        field: "Date",
        title: "Date",
        format: "{0:dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy}",
        filterable: false,

      },

      {
        field: "Rewards",
        title: "Points",
        filterable: false,
      },
    ]
  });
});
```

**My JSON**

```
[{
  "mUserID": 2024,
  "transID": "091492-1002024-2601",
  "Date": "2020-01-26T01:24:52.4904479",
  "TransactionType": "Rewards Credit",
  "Rewards": 9.0,
  "Source": "Online Feed",
  "Product": "Pullover Hoodie",
  "PurchaseAmount": 0.0,
  "OfferDesc": "",
  "Quantity": 1.0,
  "Status": "Approved",
  "TransactionTypeID": 118
}, {
  "mUserID": 2024,
  "transID": "099521-1002024-2601",
  "Date": "2020-01-26T03:38:41.7634102",
  "TransactionType": "Rewards Credit",
  "Rewards": 12.0,
  "Source": "Online Feed",
  "Product": "Precision Jacket",
  "PurchaseAmount": 0.0,
  "OfferDesc": "",
  "Quantity": 2.0,
  "Status": "Approved",
  "TransactionTypeID": 118
}, {
  "mUserID": 2024,
  "transID": "099521-1002024-2601",
  "Date": "2020-01-26T03:38:41.7725205",
  "TransactionType": "Rewards Credit",
  "Rewards": 11.0,
  "Source": "Online Feed",
  "Product": "Pinewood Jacket",
  "PurchaseAmount": 0.0,
  "OfferDesc": "",
  "Quantity": 2.0,
  "Status": "Approved",
  "TransactionTypeID": 118
}]
```

[image: Current output]

How group items which belongs to similar transaction/orderID together in my grid